# How to display data from SQL Server

Tags: php, html, sql-server, sqlsrv

I can get the connection but the data does not show. Some error occurs at this line:

```
if($result ->num_rows > 0)
```

The table names for this database is "ndtatt".
This table has 4 columns. And that just one example the value stored in this database.

1. varchar CARDNO = value 009145
2. varchar STAFF = value V0822
3. varchar NAME = value Marry
4. Varchar ATTDATE = value 2020/01/04

.

```
<?php

    $serverName = "LAPTOP-61BF65AR";

    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"LocalDatabase");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect ($serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if ($conn) {
        echo " Connection established.<br/>";
        
    }else{
        echo "Connection Failed.<br />";
        die(print_r (sqlsrv_errors() , true));
    }
    $attDate = $_GET['attDate'];
    $cardNo = $_GET['cardNo'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ndtatt WHERE ATTDATE = '$attDate' AND CARDNO = '$cardNo'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $sql);
    if($result ->num_rows> 0)
    {while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
            {?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['CARDNO']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['STAFF']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['NAME']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ATTDATE']; ?></td>
                </tr>
        <?php       
        }} 
        else {echo "0 results";}
        $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Below this is the html file :

```
    <form method="GET" action="get3.php">
            
            <h3 class="absolute" > Attendance Date :
            <input type="date" name="attDate"> </h3>

            </br></br></br>
            
            <h3 class="absolute2" > Card Number : 
            <input type="text" name="cardNo" placeholder="Card Number"> </h3>
            
            </br></br></br></br></br>
            
            <center> <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="button" />    </center>   
        
    </form>
```

The first source codes was originally for php(xampp) database with html, but I have made some changes in it, because I want to change the database(php) into sql server.

Do I need to change the entire source codes or just make some changes like I have done in the source codes given?

Does XAMPP have anything to do with SQL Server? I mean, to use the SQL server, do I need to open XAMPP when to run the codes?

Comment: It seems you have a unexpected eror. You shuld use a debugger (in Chrome, press F12 for developer tools) and see the specific error. Post the error here and maybe you will get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP is an Apache distribution containing MariaDB, PHP and Perl, so the only thing that you need to connect to SQL Server, is to install the PHP Driver for SQL Server (you are using `sqlsrv_` functions in your code).

But you have some issues with your code:

- You need to use only `sqlsrv_` functions. The calls to `$result->num_rows`, `$result->fetch_assoc()` and `$conn->close()` will raise an error.
- You need to use `"ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true` as a connection option to fetch the date/time values as strings (the default value is `false` and the values of date/time columns are returnded as PHP DateTime objects).
- The date values in your table are stored as text, so you need to transform the value of the input elements of type `"date"` to match the format in the table (`yyyy-mm-dd`). As a side note, if possible, do not store date values as text. Use the appropriate data types - `date` or `datetime2` in this case.
- Always try to use parameters in your statements to prevent SQL injection issues. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks), the `sqlsrv_query()` *function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries*.

Example, based on the code in the question:

```
<?php
// Connection
$serverName = "LAPTOP-61BF65AR";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "ReturnDatesAsStrings" => true,
    "Database" => "LocalDatabase"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn) {
    echo " Connection established.<br/>";
} else {
    echo "Connection Failed.<br />";
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Query
$attDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['attDate'])->format('Y/m/d');
$cardNo = $_GET['cardNo'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ndtatt WHERE ATTDATE = ? AND CARDNO = ?";
$params = array($attDate, $cardNo);
$result = sqlsrv_query ($conn, $sql, $params);
if ($result === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Fetch data
if (sqlsrv_has_rows($result)) {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['CARDNO']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['STAFF']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['NAME']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ATTDATE']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php       
    }
}  else {
    echo "0 results";
}

// End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

Notes:

The code from the question is driver specific, but you may try to rewrite this code using PDO ([PHP Data Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)). With PDO, using the new code, you can use any supported database (of course you need to install a database-dependant driver that implements the PDO interface).

Comment: when I run this code, I get a database connection but the data from the database does not come out. the only output  show connection establish and 0 results. I have installed the driver. Is there anything else that I overlooked or need to add?

Comment: @hanahanani What are the actual values of `$attDate` and `$cardNo`. Does the query return any rows when executed in a client tool like SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: The attDate and cardNo values are entered by the user in the textbox input (html page). When the user enters the value of attDate and cardNo, the website will display the existing data(in database) according to the value entered.

Comment: @hanahanani If there are no errors from the script and the output is `"0 results"`, then the statement returns no rows. Try to test the script without user input, something like `$attDate = '20200907;'` and `$cardNo = 12345;` (of course use the appropriate values).

Comment: If we put a specific value in this PHP code. then what do we need to put in the html file? I already try without user input but the output still same "0 result" like the fetch data part does not functioning.

Comment: @hanahanani What is the `ndtatt` table definition (column names and data types), what values are stored currently in this table? Please, edit the question and inlcude this information. Thanks.

Comment: yes, if I put specific value it can display the output base on the value stored in the database. But what if the user input other value in the HTML file . (The value exist in the database but because we specify the value in PHP file the output does not show up.)

Comment: @hanahanani You need to change the date format to match the values, stored in the table (`$attDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_GET['attDate'])->format('Y/m/d');`). The answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

The query below will retrieve two table data with join:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

Comment: I want retrieve the data in database via website